# Is a typedef to self allowed over template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, typedef, no-op

I was reading someone else's code when I came across this piece (stripped to MWE):

```cpp
template<typename R> class Test {
    public:
        typedef R R;
};
```

Here there is a `typedef` of the template parameter to itself, and it made GCC and clang (with or without `-std=c++2a`) complain:

> test.cc:3:19: error: declaration of 'typedef R Test::R' shadows template parameter

However, ICC and MSVC on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) both accept that piece.

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740962/does-a-typedef-to-self-have-any-effect), and it is suggested that a `typedef` to self is usually a no-op. However, here it does not seem to be the case. I've also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875033/clang-vs-vcerror-declaration-of-t-shadows-template-parameter) to be related but I think they should be different since here we are using a `typedef`.

So here is the question:
Is this kind of redefinition allowed by the standard?
Are there any side effects of that statement? Why might one write that?

Comment: You might write it to expose `R` to something else that knows is handed an instantiation of `Test` but doesn't necessarily know what `R` was. It's like how `std::vector<T>` has `std::vector<T>::value_type`.

Comment: Dup of [In a C++ template class, can I typedef the template parameter using the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613773/in-a-c-template-class-can-i-typedef-the-template-parameter-using-the-same-nam) or [Is it allowed to typedef a class template type argument into the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38063271/is-it-allowed-to-typedef-a-class-template-type-argument-into-the-same-name)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Oops, I thought I was careful. But still thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The name of a template parameter is not allowed to be [redeclared](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Name_resolution_for_template_parameters).

> The name of a template parameter is not allowed to be redeclared
> within its scope (including nested scopes). A template parameter is
> not allowed to have the same name as the template name.
>
> ```
> template<class T, int N>
> class Y {
>     int T;                 // error: template parameter redeclared
>     void f()
>     {
>         char T;            // error: template parameter redeclared
>     }
> };
>  
> template<class X> class X; // error: template parameter redeclared
> ```

From the standard, [[temp.local]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.local#6):

> The name of a template-parameter shall not be bound to any following
> declaration contained by the scope to which the template-parameter
> belongs. [Example 5:
>
> ```
> template<class T, int i> class Y {
>   int T;                                // error: template-parameter hidden
>   void f() {
>     char T;                             // error: template-parameter hidden
>   }
>   friend void T();                      // OK: no name bound
> };
>
> template<class X> class X;              // error: hidden by template-parameter
> ```
>
> — end example]